# NUnit CLI/C++ TestCase: Cannot use array as argument

Tags: nunit, c++-cli, nunit-3.0

I am trying to create a NUnit TestCase in C++/CLI with an array as argument. Example:

```
[NUnit::Framework::TestCase(gcnew array<int>{255, 128})]
void MyTestWithAnArray(array<int>^ myArray)
{
    NUnit::Framework::Assert::IsNotEmpty(myArray);
}
```

This compiles fine, but when running the test I get this runtime exception:

```
System.Reflection.CustomAttributeFormatException: Binary format of the specified custom attribute was invalid.
    at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs)
    at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs)
    at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
    at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
    at NUnit.Framework.Internal.MethodWrapper.GetCustomAttributes[T](Boolean inherit)
    at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Builders.DefaultTestCaseBuilder.BuildFrom(IMethodInfo method, Test parentSuite)
    at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Builders.NUnitTestFixtureBuilder.AddTestCasesToFixture(TestFixture fixture)
    at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Builders.NUnitTestFixtureBuilder.BuildFrom(ITypeInfo typeInfo, ITestFixtureData testFixtureData)
    at NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute.<BuildFrom>d__48.MoveNext()
    at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Builders.DefaultSuiteBuilder.BuildFrom(ITypeInfo typeInfo)
```

Creating the same test in C# works without any problems:

```
[TestCase(new int[] {255, 128})]
public void MyArrayTest(int[] myArray)
{
    Assert.IsNotEmpty(myArray);
}
```

Does anybody have an idea of what I might be doing wrong?
Used NUnit version is 3.8.1

Comment: The problem might be the fact that the produced IL does not include the array type signature (ELEMENT_TYPE_SZARRAY & ELEMENT_TYPE_I4).

Have you ever figured this one out?